# Update same table using sum and case not working

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_2' at line 3' when trying to run this update statement.  The statement is trying to update the table with results from a sum line (as PTSD_Total) if there are less than 2 missing values.  The code works when run as a SELECT.  The PTSD_Total column exists in the table as a tinyint (as values are small) which are currently filled with nulls.  Any help appreciated at spotting my error.

```
    UPDATE mytablename
    SET PTSD_Total = ((SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_1,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_2,0)))+
(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_3,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_4,0)))+
(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_5,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_6,0)))+
(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_7,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_8,0)))+
(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_9,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_10,0))))
    HAVING (SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN 
PTSD2E_2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_3 IS NULL THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN 
PTSD2E_5 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_6 IS NULL THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_7 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN
 PTSD2E_8 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_9 IS NULL THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_10 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) < 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching and reordering... this works... in case it helps anyone else!

```
     UPDATE mytablename o 
        INNER JOIN
        (
           SELECT your_ID, 

((SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_1,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_2,0)))+
    (SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_3,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_4,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_5,0)))+
    (SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_6,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_7,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_8,0)))+
    (SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_9,0)))+(SUM(IFNULL(PTSD2E_10,0)))) AS PTSD_Total, 

(SUM(CASE 
    WHEN PTSD2E_1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_2 IS NULL THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN 
    PTSD2E_4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_5 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 
    0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_6 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN 
    PTSD2E_7 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_8 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 
    0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN PTSD2E_9 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN 
    PTSD2E_10 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS PTSD_Num_Missing

           FROM mytablename
           GROUP BY your_ID
           HAVING PTSD_Num_Missing < 3
        ) i ON o.your_ID = i.your_ID
        SET o.PTSD_Total = i.PTSD_Total
        ;
```